python flask and mysql database
please how can i retrieve an image from mysql database and display it in my html website
these are what I have tried:
app.py
@app.route('/customerDetails', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def customerDetails():
message = ''
if "logged in" in session and 'admin' == session['role']:
  `user = session["username"]`
  `ViewCustomerId = request.args.get('customerid')`
  `cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)`
  `cur. execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id= % s', (ViewCustomerId))`
  View customer = cur .fetchone()
  if `Viewcustomer `!= None:
     customer = `Viewcustomer`
  else:
     message = 'this customer does not exist in your database'
  cur.execute('SELECT image FROM user WHERE id= % s', (ViewCustomerId))
  image = cur.fetchone()
  image = base64.b64encode(Image.open(io.BytesIO(str)))
  return render_template("customerDetails.html", user=user,
  customer=customer, image=image, message=message)
   else:
      return redirect(url_for("home"))

customerDetails.htm
<img class="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ image_data }}" alt="image" width="350" height="350" />

Please fix the indentation. And why do you have backticks distributed all over the code?

You need a comma in (ViewCustomerId,) to make it a tuple.

Why do you need a second query for image? The image will already be one of the elements of the customer tuple.

{{ image_data }} should be just {{ image }}.
